# Unable to reach API proxy - Apigee

Tags: deployment, proxy, apigee

After proxy bundle deployed to Test environment, unable to reach the base URL of the deployed proxy
The requested URL is not available.

Requested URL:

http://v1/

Recommendations

Ensure the URL is entered correctly.

Refresh your browser window.

Try again later.

Comment: If you want to get a good answer.  You might want to rephase your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you include the full URL, including domain, in your browser.  For instance, the full URL may be https://aktest-prod.apigee.net/v1.  You can get the full URL in the API overview screen (e.g., http://cl.ly/image/1h0v2T0W3e0y).